# In image matching, what is the role of model?

Tags: computer-vision

I am studying image matching techniques. I am studying an image feature extraction method such as SIFT and matching technique such as Bag of Features. I have been reading few articles about this computer vision field and noticed that they talk about "model" all the time. What is this model and what's the role of a system? They talk about "learning the model." what does this mean??
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Learning the model" typically means "training a classifier".  For example, if you use the Bag of Features approach to distinguish images of dogs from images of cats, you would train a "dog-vs-cat" classifier.  The output of the training procedure is often called a "model", which you can then use to classify an image as "dog" or "cat".

I think the reason the term "model" is used, is to avoid the ambiguity of the term "classifier". A classifier could mean a classification algorithm, such as a support vector machine (SVM), or it could mean the result of training on some specific data set using a classification algorithm. The term "model" removes the ambiguity.  You can train a model to distinguish between cats and dogs using a linear SVM classifier.